# element.all(locator) is returning [object Object] in protractor node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, protractor

Am trying to fetch the list of files in a folder from application.But the list is returning Object.Please see the below code and help me resolve it.

```
var FilesInFolder = by.xpath("xpath");

getListOfElements = async function(loc) {
  try {
    let list = await element.all(loc);
    console.log("list of elements: " +list); 
    return list;
  } catch(err) {
      throw err;
  }
}

verifyXZ=async function(fileName){
              
    var listOfFiles = await getElements(FilesInFolder);
    for (var i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
    var files = await browser.get(listOfFiles[i].getText());
 }          
}
```

Output :

```
list of elements: [object Object]

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE] [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "url" argument must be of type string. Received an instance of ElementFinder
```

Comment: what if `JSON.stringify(list)`

Comment: Showing the below output :   TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
           --> starting at object with constructor 'ProtractorBrowser'
           |     property 'debugHelper' -> object with constructor 'DebugHelper'
           --- property 'browserUnderDebug_' closes the circle

Comment: `browser.get` is used to open a url, you're trying to open... elements?? doesn't make sense

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved after the below change :

```
let list = await (element.all(locator).getText());
```

Comment: actually it's even simplier `let list = await element.all(locator).getText();` you don't need those brackets